# Seemingly inconsistent appearance of the Part error message

Tags: error-tracking

I'm new to mathematica and have been trying to create a graph with edge weights defined by patterns. Here is a code snippet:

```
n = 2;
m = 2;
vWeightDown = q;
list = Range[n*m]; 
Table[
G = GridGraph[{m, n}, 
    EdgeWeight -> { 
       _?(p[[First[#]]] > p[[#[[2]]]] &) ->  
       vWeightDown
    }
];
MatrixForm[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[G]]
,
{p, Permutations[list]}]
```

For a permutation p, this gives an edge (i,j) weight vWeightDown if p(i)>p(j).
Running this code, I get errors like "Part specification p[[2]] is longer than depth of object," but only *sometimes*. In particular, this error message only occurs 4 times, in the first and third permutations. In all of the other cases, the result is exactly as expected. Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please gives us a _complete_ working (and non-working) example, that is: include ``m``, ``n`` and ``vWeightDown``. Also, why do you multiply ``GridGraph`` with ``MatrixForm``? And why do you assign values to ``G`` in a table? – they will get overwritten in each iteration.

Comment: Oops, there should be a semicolon in between GridGraph and MatrixForm, that was an error in my question, not the code.

Comment: I just edited the post to include n,m, and vWeightDown

Comment: I don't know why this is happening. Also, **warning to others**, evaluating some of the ``GridGraph``s with given ``EdgeWeight`` with pattern crashes my kernel. As a workaround, you can first create a ``GridGraph``, and then assign the edge weights: ``Table[With[{G = GridGraph[{m, n}]}, Graph[G, EdgeWeight -> (If[p[[#[[1]]]] > p[[#[[2]]]], vWeightDown, 1] & /@ EdgeList[G])]], {p, Permutations[list]}]``

Comment: I don't think you can provide that syntax to `EdgeWeight`.  It should be just a list of values. Do you want the value 1 for the default weight and `vWeightDOwn` if $p(i)>p(j)$?

Comment: q is not defined and Wrong syntax: `{_?((p[[First[#]]] > p[[#[[2]]]]) &) -> vWeightDown}` the pattern test should return "True"

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 2;
m = 2;
vWeightDown = q;
list = Range[n*m];
Module[{G},
 Table[
  G = GridGraph[{m, n}];
  G = GridGraph[{m, n}, 
    EdgeWeight -> (If[p[[#1]] > p[[#2]], q, 1] & @@@ EdgeList@G)];
  MatrixForm[WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[G]],
  {p, Permutations[list]}]
 ]
```

Alternatively, one can use the more new-user friendly

```
EdgeWeight -> Table[If[p[[edge[[1]]]] > p[[edge[[2]]]], q, 1], {edge, EdgeList[G]}]
```

The point is to make the list of edge weights from the list of edges of the graph.